# Filtering List of Maps in Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-stream, maps

I have a list of maps data structure.  I need to filter the list by searching for a value in each of the maps (the result will always only be a single map).  The below code shows my two approaches to doing this.  Although my Lambda approach works, it seems bloated to me.  I get the sense I'm missing something simple here and there is a more concise Lambda that could be used instead of this one.  I'd appreciate any suggestions for making the Lambda better.  Thanks much.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Temp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("map1-key1", "map1-value-1");
    map1.put("map1-key2", "map1-value-2");
    map1.put("map1-key3", "map1-value-3");
    
    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("map2-key1", "map2-value-1");
    map2.put("map2-key2", "some_wanted_value");
    map2.put("map2-key3", "map2-value-3");

    Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("map3-key1", "map3-value-1");
    map3.put("map3-key2", "map3-value-2");
    map3.put("map3-key3", "map3-value-3");

    List<Map<String, String>> LOMs = new ArrayList<>();
    
    LOMs.add(map1);
    LOMs.add(map2);
    LOMs.add(map3);

    String column = "some_wanted_value";
      
    // Imperative method.  
    Map<String, String> x = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map<String, String> lom : LOMs) {
      if(lom.containsValue(column)) {
        x = lom;
        break;
      }
    }
    x.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + "->" + v));
    /*
    map2-key1->map2-value-1
    map2-key3->map2-value-3
    map2-key2->some_wanted_value
     */

    // Lambda method.
    Map<String, String> y = LOMs
      .stream()
      .filter(s -> s.containsValue(column))
      .flatMap(s -> s.entrySet().stream())
      .map(s -> s.toString().split("="))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1], (o, n) -> o));
    y.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + "->" + v));
    /*
    map2-key1->map2-value-1
    map2-key3->map2-value-3
    map2-key2->some_wanted_value
     */

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to limit the results of the sprint to a single result to match your imperative solution, no need to overcomplicate it by collecting it again

```java
LOMs.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.containsValue(column))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseGet(Collections::emptyMap)
        .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "->" + v));
```

An alternative would be to use `ifPresent` instead of `orElseGet` to make sure you don't unnecessarily instantiate a map, it depends on what you need of course

```java
LOMs.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.containsValue(column))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(map -> map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "->" + v)));
```

This prints the same result as your imperative solution and the other one involving streams

```
map2-key1->map2-value-1
map2-key3->map2-value-3
map2-key2->some_wanted_value
```

Comment: Thanks, Yassin.  Good options, both, and a big improvement on the original Lambda.

Comment: You're welcome @Jack feel free to upvote / accept the answer as to close this question and make obvious this answer helped you out

Comment: Thanks, Yassin.  I upvoted.  Because my rep is only at an 11, the upvote is recorded but not shown.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Jack no problem, acceptation of the answer is possible normally even with 11 pts, that would already help close the question

Answer (score 0):

It should be way much simpler:

```java
Map<String, String> result = LOMs.stream()
    .filter(map -> map.containsValue(column))
    .findFirst() // returns Optional
    .get(); // use get if you're sure that you always have one result
```

If it's possible that you get no result, use `Optional#orElse` (for values) or `Optional#orElseGet` (for functional interfaces).

You can read more about Optional, for example, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional).

Comment: Using `get()` is an anti-pattern unfortunately, try `orElse` / `orElseGet` or `ifPresent`